# SQL Server CE 4 Asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I'm trying to create async calls to SQL Server CE 4 database. As I understand there is no asynchronous processing param for connection string and `BeginExecuteReader` command for the command object. My aim is to provide async calls to `SELECT` command to make big lists in app work faster and more responsive to user, no need for full CRUD.

So is there any good solution for that? And whether it is worth go async in this situation? Right now I have sync calls for all my SQL Server CE commands and open/close connection for each call.

I know how to make basic async calls but in this situation i'm not quite sure this is a right decision. The first idea is to leave connection always opened and just call it in async manner. Not trying yet but feel like it is not right way.

Appreciate any suggestions and ideas.

Comment: Try before posting (unless your operation is on a production machine). That's the most effective way to learn things.

Comment: A Backgroundworker and data Binding?

Comment: @ErikEJ Can you please explain more. I don't see any relation here. Right now I'm calling async method to get items from database only in logic that responsible for particular operation in app. All other calls (and even these one) are made in sync way. So basicly I have only one feature in app that make async call. I call it by using delegate so no need any BackgroundWorker out there. So far everything works great.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for advice. I have a bunch of data logic that need to be reshape for sake of one async operation. So I ask first for advice from someone who face similar issue to be sure that this is a good idea.